# Mobile apps and local html files

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am currently working on my first mobile app and am using Intels XDK(uses cordova).

I am having trouble getting a jquery mobile script to work on some of my pages.

Basically it works on my index.html page but will not work on other HTML pages that are served locally.

My question is can I build an app with more than one html file? or is it all via the index html ?

I can get it too work with one file using jquery mobile but wanted to build using html pages similar to that used in a website. Is this possible or even worth it. The extra pages were intended to give me more opportunity to advertise.

Hopefully this is a simple one. I have seen a few questions regarding this  (or similar like jquery mobile not working) but they were without anwser.

Comment: Yes, you can; the Cordova documentation says how.

Comment: I can load the pages using the jquery mobile but the jquery scripts do not work. I missing something here. I looked at the documentation and found it very hard to understand this being my first full encounter with the framework. I not even sure if I am looking at the correct part. I am not looking simply for you to write my code just an understanding of why this happens and a nudge the the right direction as to what I should be looking at

Comment: How are you loading the other pages? Your problem may be because of the way you go from page to page (for example if you're using JQM) or it could be a secutity issue linked with the whitelist plugin (may need to allow loading local js in the Content-Security-Policy meta tag in your html file)

Comment: @QuickFix I am experimenting. I have the app working with JQM using the #page1, #page2 etc. Where all pages are on the index.html. However when I try to redirect to say about.html a seperate file(local- sibling). I get the content but JQM is not working. I know cordova is designed for single page apps but I am sure from ready other questions that this functionality is possible

Comment: Does your multi page app work in a regular browser? (just to be sure if your issue is not linked to JQM navigation)